# Executing JavaScript in a Haml form using Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to use `jquery.datetimeentry` and I am a newbie having trouble with the javascript. if I put:

```
$(function () {
    $.datetimeEntry.setDefaults({spinnerImage: 'spinnerDefault.png'});
    $('#defaultEntry').datetimeEntry();
    $('#dateEntry').datetimeEntry({datetimeFormat: 'O/D/Y'});
    $('#timeEntry').datetimeEntry({datetimeFormat: 'H:Ma'});
});
```

in my application.js file it seems like it should just work but it doesn't.
However if I put the following in my form (with haml) it works:

```
%script{:type=>"text/javascript"}
  $('#dateEntry').datetimeEntry({datetimeFormat: 'D/O/Y'});
```

I think it is bad form to put it in line so what do I need to do to make it work from my application.js file - or should I put it someplace else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function() { });`

So here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function () {
    $.datetimeEntry.setDefaults({spinnerImage: 'spinnerDefault.png'});
    $('#defaultEntry').datetimeEntry();
    $('#dateEntry').datetimeEntry({datetimeFormat: 'O/D/Y'});
    $('#timeEntry').datetimeEntry({datetimeFormat: 'H:Ma'});
  });
});
```

By the way, when inline javascript is a must, use HAML's `:javascript` hook.

```
:javascript
   alert('hello');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer but I realized that there is still something wrong in my asset pipeline

Comment: Whats wrong with your asset pipeline? I can probably help, I have a fairly good knowledge of how that works